# Accessing an array by string value

Tags: arrays, swift, string

I have two type of arrays: one for storage the category name:

```
struct Category {
    var title : String
    var dataArrayName : String
}

var Categories = [
    Category(title: "First Title", dataArrayName: "firstDataArray"),
    Category(title: "Second Title", dataArrayName: "secondDataArray")
]
```

and another one for storage the category data:

```
var firstDataArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] // Data Array 1
var secondDataArray = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10] // Data Array 2
```

Then, in tableView didSelectRowAt indexPath I want to access `firstDataArray` by `dataArrayName` from `Categories` (to push the data array to another View Controller).

I get value of `dataArrayName` via line `Categories[indexPath.row].dataArrayName` but I don't know how to access array because I get a String result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you could set a "dataArrayName" with the data [Int]. Because, when you set the Array Data Before the categories, you can access this var like this:

```
struct Category {
    var title : String
    var dataArrayName : [Int]
}

var firstDataArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] // Data Array 1
var secondDataArray = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10] // Data Array 2

var categories = [
    Category(title: "First Title", dataArrayName: firstDataArray),
    Category(title: "Second Title", dataArrayName: secondDataArray)
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably should access to arrayData not by name, it's very bad practice in programming. Instead of it use instance of `Array`, like this:

```
struct Category {
    var title : String
    var dataArray : [Int]
}

var firstDataArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] // Data Array 1
var secondDataArray = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10] // Data Array 2

var categories = [
    Category(title: "First Title", dataArray: firstDataArray),
    Category(title: "Second Title", dataArray: secondDataArray)
]
```

And finally access to the arrayData:

```
print(categories[indexPath.row].dataArray)
```